# Find all functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that satisfy $f(x) + 3 f\left( \frac {x-1}{x} \right) = 7x$ for all nonzero $x$.

Tags: functional-equations

Find all functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that satisfy $$ f(x)  + 3 f\left( \frac {x-1}{x} \right) = 7x $$
for all nonzero $x$.

---

I don't know what's going on today, my brain is not moving!  I'm stuck on this problem.  Solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I mean, come on, the question is identical, and that one was asked within one hour ago.

Comment: @SimpleArt  Math Stackexchange better come up with a better search system because the other question did not pop up when I did a search for duplicates.

Comment: I cannot argue for that, but it suspicious when identical questions show up within a one hour time frame.  Also note that it is difficult to search for specific equations and newly posted questions may not show up the top of the search.